# .Net Upgrade Assistant fails on Converting Project to SDK Style - System.IO.IOException

Tags: .net, vb.net, winforms

I'm in the process of updating an old VB.Net Winforms application from .Net Framework to .Net. The solution has 12 Projects, of which 11 have updated with no issues. When trying to update the Startup Project which contains the apps UI, it fails on the first step with the following error in the logs:

```
Microsoft.UpgradeAssistant.Transformers.ProjectSdkStyleTransformer
    info: Converting project 'C:\source\CommTool\Application\Commission.vbproj' to SDK style.
    error: System.IO.IOException,    at System.IO.__Error.WinIOError(Int32 errorCode, String maybeFullPath)
   at System.IO.File.InternalCopy(String sourceFileName, String destFileName, Boolean overwrite, Boolean checkHost)
   at Microsoft.UpgradeAssistant.Services.FileSystemExtensions.DirectoryCopy(IFileSystem fileSystem, String sourceDirectory, String targetDirectory, ISet`1 excludeFolders, Boolean recursive) in D:\a\_work\1\s\src\engine\Services\FileSystem\FileSystemExtensions.cs:line 23
   at Microsoft.UpgradeAssistant.Services.FileSystemExtensions.DirectoryCopy(IFileSystem fileSystem, String sourceDirectory, String targetDirectory, ISet`1 excludeFolders, Boolean recursive) in D:\a\_work\1\s\src\engine\Services\FileSystem\FileSystemExtensions.cs:line 31
   at Microsoft.UpgradeAssistant.Services.FileSystemExtensions.DirectoryCopy(IFileSystem fileSystem, String sourceDirectory, String targetDirectory, ISet`1 excludeFolders, Boolean recursive) in D:\a\_work\1\s\src\engine\Services\FileSystem\FileSystemExtensions.cs:line 31
   at Microsoft.UpgradeAssistant.Services.FileSystemExtensions.DirectoryCopy(IFileSystem fileSystem, String sourceDirectory, String targetDirectory, ISet`1 excludeFolders, Boolean recursive) in D:\a\_work\1\s\src\engine\Services\FileSystem\FileSystemExtensions.cs:line 31
   at Microsoft.UpgradeAssistant.Transformers.ProjectSdkStyleTransformer.<RunAsync>d__2.MoveNext() in D:\a\_work\1\s\src\engine\Transformers\Project\ProjectSdkStyleTransformer.cs:line 65
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.UpgradeAssistant.Operations.Operation.<RunTransformerAsync>d__23.MoveNext() in D:\a\_work\1\s\src\engine\Operations\Operation.cs:line 387
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at Microsoft.UpgradeAssistant.Operations.Operation.<RunNodeTransformersAsync>d__21.MoveNext() in D:\a\_work\1\s\src\engine\Operations\Operation.cs:line 274
    info: Done
```

Because of this, I am unable to continue working on the solution as this project is still referencing .Net Framework and everything else is .Net.

I've tried different versions of .Net (6,7,8), all with the same outcome, and checked the file permissions of the .vbproj files in the different projects and they are the same across all 12 projects.

Am I missing something obvious here?

Comment: Usually see that error when the file can't be accessed. There may be an issue with the file permissions, or more likely something has accessed the file and keeping it open so any attempts to access it by another app throws an error.  (Visual Studio is notorious for keeping things open!) Try logging out or restarting the machine.

Comment: i'm running into this with C# projects so its not confined to just vb.net